# Linking Google Sheets to Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I would like to find a way (through scripts?) to connect dates in my Google Sheets to show up in my Google Calendar. Is there a function to do this?  If not, is there a way to program this?

We use Google Sheets for project management of several programs.  The dates in there need to be "pushed" to Google calendar in order to allow calendar functions for these programs such as sending reminders etc.

Thank you for any assistance on this!

Jodi

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to create Calendar events using scripts. Take a look at the [scheduling an appointment section](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/helpdesk_tutorial#section4) in this tutorial.

Comment: That link no longer contains the aforementioned tutorial.